# Debugger doesn't locate symbols in source when INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION is enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I've been switching a project to CMake and VSCode on my Mac, and encountered a baffling problem: when I enable LTO/IPO, VSCode's C++ debugger doesn't highlight the execution line when breaking.  This appears to affect any build target for which I enable IPO.

Here's a minimum example demonstrating the problem:

```cpp
[main.cpp]
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is some text!" << std::endl;
    __asm__("int $3"); // Alternatively, use a breakpoint
    return 0;
}
```

```
[CMakeLists.txt]
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.0)
project(TestLTODebugging)

include(CheckIPOSupported)
check_ipo_supported()

add_executable(example main.cpp)
set_target_properties(example PROPERTIES
    INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE
)
```

I'm using Clang and Ninja, using [quick-debugging](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/debugging.html#quick-debugging) via VSCode's CMake Tools extension.  When run, the app appears to pause as expected, but the line is not highlighted:
[image: VSCode debugger pauses, but doesn't highlight affected line]
And if all I do is turn off IPO/LTO, the issue goes away:
[image: With LTO off, current line of code is highlighted correctly]

Anyone know where to look for the problem?  I'm new to CMake and using VSCode for C++, but this seems super basic and I can't find anything online about this problem.  I've had no problems with this when generating an Xcode project with the same source.

While I'm primarily going to be debugging without optimizations, the project I'm working on requires working with optimizations enabled a lot of the time, and I want the debugger to work.  I appreciate any help or advice.

**EDIT**: I've confirmed that this issue does not occur on my PC, where I also tested with Ninja, Clang, and the VSCode debugger.  So the problem is either with my Mac environment or is Mac-specific?

**EDIT 2**: I've now confirmed this affects me with both Ninja and Make files on my Mac.  Additionally, both Ninja.build and compile_commands.json (when using Make) show that the only difference between enabling and disabling IPO is the addition of the `-flto=thin` flag.  The `-g` flag is never removed, and using `nm` in Terminal shows that the debug symbols are still being generated.  I'm now more confident that this is a bug with VS Code or CMake Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem -- in my case I source annotations for Instruments were missing.

From [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-flto):

> **Note**
>
> On Darwin, when using `-flto` along with `-g` and compiling and linking in separate steps, you also need to pass `-Wl,-object_path_lto,<lto-filename>.o` at the linking step to instruct the ld64 linker not to delete the temporary object file generated during Link Time Optimization (this flag is automatically passed to the linker by Clang if compilation and linking are done in a single step). This allows debugging the executable as well as generating the `.dSYM` bundle using *dsymutil*(1).

Additional information [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues/354).

TL;DR: just add `-Wl,-object_path_lto,lto.o` to your linker options -- e.g. for CMake: `add_link_options(-Wl,-object_path_lto,lto.o)`.

Comment: I really appreciate your response.  I believe you've hit the nail right on the head as to the cause: adding those options worked immediately.  It just took me a month or two to get around to it.

Comment: However, I wanted to follow up on this, because while this works fine in my simple example, it requires manually specifying the path to each object file.  Is there a CMake-ey way you're aware of for automatically specifying this for every object file?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean — are you talking about multiple targets? If it’s a single target I recall that’s all you need.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood. I thought the Clang docs were saying that you have to pass the path to any object file you want to keep the debug symbols for. I now understand that "<lto-filename>" is simply what you choose to call a single temp file that's normally discarded.

I'm not exactly clear on why there's an extra object file generated just for LTO (I will need to learn more about it, I suppose) but I believe I can easily implement this solution now.  Thanks!

Comment: Although, thinking about this now, I'm not sure my suggestion to use `add_link_options` would work in the case of multiple targets with LTO. Perhaps in that case you'd want to use something like `target_link_options(${TARGET} -Wl,-object_path_lto,lto_${TARGET}.o)` so as to have different LTO object files for each target. However, I didn't test this, it's just a hunch.

Comment: I believe `target_link_options` is the "modern/best practice" way of adding options anyways, so I've been using it.  What I've found is that `-object_path_lto` specifies the folder name which receives the LTO object files.  You can specify the same path for every target; a unique name is generated for each LTO object.